# INITCAP and LOWER without losing necessary capitalization

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table (in Oracle 11gR2) full of addresses (mostly US) as Address line 1, line 2 and so on. Most of the Line 1 was typed in with all upper case letters and we now have a task at hand to convert them to lower case with initcap.

For example-

```
ADD_1
-------------
1234 KUALA STREET
333 E THOUSAND OAKS BLVD
8787 167TH PLACE SE
2370 NE HWY 99W
14010 NORTH US HWY 183
```

The Lower case and initcap was achieved using the simple query below-

```
select initcap(lower(add_1)) from address;

ADD_1
-------------
1234 Kuala Street
333 E Thousand Oaks Blvd
8787 167Th Place Se
2370 Ne Hwy 99W
14010 North Us Hwy 183
```

Now (although a cosmetic issue) the problem is clear, looking at rows 2, 3 and 4 above you can see that `SE` was changed to `Se` , `NE` was changed to `Ne` and `US` was changed to `Us`. We need to retain the capitalization for the directions such as `NE`,`SE`,`NW`,and `SW` and also for `US`. Again, this is a cosmetic issue but this data will be interfaced over to a customer facing mobile application so it needs to look correct. Is there a better way of achieving this other than writing a nested `REPLACE()` function on the column or a PLSQL? I would think of using `REGEX` functions but couldn't think of a way to come up with the pattern without nesting `REGEX_REPLACE`.

Comment: I have spent a little time thinking on this and there are a number of solutions but you have excluded two types.  I would like to know what your intention is.  My interpretation is that you want "A single select statement that is easy to read and correctly capitalises the street names in an address while retaining the correct capitalisation for known abbreviations".  Please confirm.

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct. I need to retain the capitalization of abbreviations like NE (Noth east), SW (South West), US (United States) etc. although this can be achieved with a PLSQL script, I am trying to find out if it is possible to come up with some sort of regular expression pattern to match and replace 'Ne' for 'NE', 'Sw' for 'SW' and so on. For now the pattern would be limited to replacing/matching these 5 - NE, SE, NW, SW, and US (or USA).

Comment: Thanks.  I understand this is not possible in a single pattern for regexp_replace and look forward to someone informing me otherwise.  If you are interested in how I would code a PL/SQL function to achieve your requirement I am happy to post that.  Good luck.